# nullpointerexception thrown while fields are not null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Hello I have created a application with several buttons in it. but when I press a button I get the NullPointerException. The strange thing here is that nothing is empty ( null )

here a code example

```
public class MuseumPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JTextField kaartnummer;
private JTextField uur, minuut;
private JButton aankomst, vertrek, overzicht, sluiting;

private int hour;
private int minute;
private final int REFRESH = 1000;

MuseumRegistratie museum;

public MuseumPanel(MuseumRegistratie museum) {
    // zorg ervoor dat de huidige tijd wordt opgehaald.
    javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(REFRESH, this);
    timer.start();

    kaartnummer = new JTextField(15);
    uur = new JTextField(2);
    minuut = new JTextField(2);
    aankomst = new JButton("Komt binnen");
    aankomst.addActionListener(this);
    vertrek = new JButton("Vertrekt");
    vertrek.addActionListener(this);
    overzicht = new JButton("aantal aanwezig");
    overzicht.addActionListener(this);
    sluiting = new JButton("sluiting");
    sluiting.addActionListener(this);

    add(new JLabel("Kaartnummer"));
    add(kaartnummer);
    add(new JLabel("tijdstip van aankomst of vertrek "));
    add(uur);
    add(new JLabel(" uur en "));
    add(minuut);
    add(new JLabel(" minuten"));
    add(aankomst);
    add(vertrek);
    add(overzicht);
    add(sluiting);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    uur.setText("" + hour);
    minuut.setText("" + minute);

    // aankomst
    if(e.getSource() == aankomst) {
        try {

            museum.checkIn(kaartnummer.getText(), hour, minute);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {

            System.out.println("cardnumber: " + kaartnummer.getText() + " hour " + hour + " minute " + minute);
        }
    }
    // vertrek
    if(e.getSource() == vertrek) {
        museum.checkOut(kaartnummer.getText(), hour, minute);
    }
    // overzicht
    if(e.getSource() == overzicht) {
        museum.getAantalAanwezig();
    }
    // sluiting
    if(e.getSource() == sluiting) {
        museum.sluitRegistratie();
    }
}
}
```

When pressing this button for example I get the exception with every variable correctly.. Does anyone know how this appears and how to solve it?

Comment: Is the museum object null?

Comment: except he is printing it in the exception and says there is a value there.  Therefore I'm assuming it isn't.

Comment: i've added the whole class, might make some things clear..

Comment: @ajon nice find! I think you are right. The constructor is missing something like `this.museum = museum;`

Comment: Any reason why you did not simply look at the exception stack trace?  It would point you right at the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be assigning a value to `museum` in your constructor, yet you dereference it in a lot of places.  You'd want to do this:

```
this.museum = museum;
```

somewhere in your constructor.  Alternatively, rename the variable so you don't accidentally do `museum = museum`, which would have no effect.

Answer (score 3):

Without further information I would assume that the museum object is null which would trigger the nullpointerexception when you try to call museum.checkIn.

Looking at the Code museum is definitely null.  in the constructor you should include:

```
this.museum = museum;
```

Assuming the museum object you pass in is NOT null then everything else should work.

Comment: The the sysout would not do anything because of kaartnummer.getText()

Comment: @MasterCassim yeah, dint see the sysout :)

Comment: He says "nothing is empty" I'm guessing the OP assumes that because of the println.

Comment: But how is it possible that i see all 3 variables?

Comment: The other 3 variables are not related at all to the museum object.  They are related to the karrtnummer object and the Calendar object.  Those can be non null, but if the museum object is null then museum.checkin will always throw a null pointer exception.